# UserScript to take actions based on Key Press?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, userscripts, onkeydown

I'm struggling with the syntax for this user script I'm trying to write, which should basically follow this logic:

```
IF (LeftArrowKeyIsPressed) THEN doSomething;
ELSE IF (RightArrowKeyIsPressed) THEN doSomethingElse;
ELSE IF (any other key pressed) THEN doNothing;
```

Can someone help me out with the code syntax for structuring the check for the keypress?  Assume an `onkeydown` event is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event listener, probably to the window, using `addEventListener`. Then switch off the `Event.which` value to do what you want.

Here's the code. [**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uzxjf/1/):

```
/*--- Get or set the codes for the arrow keys.
    Firefox gives us nice constants, Chrome does not.
*/
KeyEvent        = (typeof KeyEvent === "object")  ?  KeyEvent  :  [];
const LEFT_KEY  = KeyEvent.DOM_VK_LEFT   ||  37;
const RIGHT_KEY = KeyEvent.DOM_VK_RIGHT  ||  39;

window.addEventListener ("keydown", keyboardHandler, false);

function keyboardHandler (zEvent) {
    var bBlockDefaultAction = false;

    //--- Assume we want only the plain keys, not the modified versions.
    if (zEvent.altKey  ||  zEvent.ctrlKey  ||  zEvent.shiftKey) {
        //-- Do nothing (most user-friendly option, in most cases).
    }
    else {
        if (zEvent.which == LEFT_KEY) {
            //DO LEFT KEY ACTION HERE.
            bBlockDefaultAction = true;
        }
        else if (zEvent.which == RIGHT_KEY) {
            //DO RIGHT KEY ACTION HERE.
            bBlockDefaultAction = true;
        }
    }

    if (bBlockDefaultAction) {
        zEvent.preventDefault ();
        zEvent.stopPropagation ();
    }
}
```

---

This code works on userscripts-applicable browsers (not IE).  The jQuery version is the same except change the `addEventListener` line to:

```
$(window).keydown (keyboardHandler);
```

Comment: Thanks, man, I've been struggling with the structures of the if system, so this is very useful.  This should be flagged as a userscript guide, IMO :)